# Install pyodbc on Colab using pip. I got an error

Tags: google-colaboratory, pyodbc

i got an error when installing pyodbc on colab. it works on my local. anything else i should do to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both apt and pip to install pyodbc

```
!apt install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc
```

Then you can import it.

```
import pyodbc
```